# Called function not executing code inside function

Tags: function, powershell

Basically, I am trying to create a script to allow my GPU miner to choose what settings to run the miner with (to select what GPU to use with the miner) and this is the code that I have written for my PowerShell script:

```
$choice = '0'
function Get-Choice()
{
Write-Host 'Here are your choices:'
Write-Host '1. All GPUs'
Write-Host '2. GPU 0'
Write-Host '3. GPU 1'
$choice = Read-Host -Prompt 'Type the number and press enter to select what GPU(s) to mine with'
}

Get-Choice

function Set-Gpu0
{
Write-Host 'GPU 1 Chosen'
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
miner.exe --server us-east.zec.slushpool.com --port 4444 --user ColinAndress.Colin --pass x --cuda_devices 1 --intensity 64 --eexit 3
Set-Gpu0
}

function Set-Gpu1
{
Write-Host 'GPU 0 Chosen'
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
miner.exe --server us-east.zec.slushpool.com --port 4444 --user ColinAndress.Colin --pass x --cuda_devices 0 --intensity 64 --eexit 3
Set-Gpu1
}

function Set-All
{
Write-Host 'All GPUs Chosen'
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
miner.exe --server us-east.zec.slushpool.com --port 4444 --user ColinAndress.Colin --pass x --cuda_devices 0 1 --intensity 64 64 --eexit 3
Set-All 
}

function Is-Invalid
{
Write-Host 'Option is invalid. Pick again'
Get-Choice
}

If(-NOT($choice-eq1-or2-or3)){Is-Invalid}
Elseif($choice-eq1){Set-All}
Elseif($choice-eq2){Set-Gpu1}
Elseif($choice-eq3){Set-Gpu0}
```

The code will ask the user to pick one of the 3 options by inputting the number, and that gets interpreted at the bottom and calls a function that corresponds with the option. The problem is, once it calls the function at the bottom, it just exits the script without running any of the code in the function. Here is what it looks like when run:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> C:\Users\Colin\Documents\.GPU Miner\0.3.4b\Slushpool Miner.ps1
Here are your choices:
1. All GPUs
2. GPU 0
3. GPU 1
Type the number and press enter to select what GPU(s) to mine with: 3

PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>
```

I also tried doing it by running the code directly in the "If" statements and it returned the same outcome as the code above. Could someone please try and help me understand what I am doing wrong here? I am new to Powershell and I don't understand a lot of the guides online for functions as they are really vague/don't fit with what I need them for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your implementation. Here is one:
You can't write

```
If(-NOT($choice -eq 1 -or 2-or 3)){Is-Invalid}
```

It is

```
if(-not($choice -eq 1 -or $choice -eq 2 -or $choice -eq 3)){Is-Invalid}
```

And it can be written more tersely with:

```
if(-not($choice -in 1..3)){Is-Invalid}
```

The minimal change I can see to make it work is this:

```
[int]$choice = 0
function Get-Choice()
{
    Write-Host 'Here are your choices:'
    Write-Host '1. All GPUs'
    Write-Host '2. GPU 0'
    Write-Host '3. GPU 1'
    $choice = Read-Host -Prompt 'Type the number and press enter to select what GPU(s) to mine with'
    [int]$choice
}

function Set-Gpu0
{
    Write-Host 'GPU 1 Chosen'
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
    miner.exe --server us-east.zec.slushpool.com --port 4444 --user ColinAndress.Colin --pass x --cuda_devices 1 --intensity 64 --eexit 3
    Set-Gpu0
}

function Set-Gpu1
{
    Write-Host 'GPU 0 Chosen'
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
    miner.exe --server us-east.zec.slushpool.com --port 4444 --user     ColinAndress.Colin --pass x --cuda_devices 0 --intensity 64 --eexit 3
    Set-Gpu1
}

function Set-All
{
    Write-Host 'All GPUs Chosen'
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
    miner.exe --server us-east.zec.slushpool.com --port 4444 --user     ColinAndress.Colin --pass x --cuda_devices 0 1 --intensity 64 64 --eexit 3
    Set-All 
}

function Is-Invalid
{
    Write-Host 'Option is invalid. Pick again'
    Get-Choice # Not going to work
}

$choice = Get-Choice
If(-NOT($choice -in 1..3))
{
    Is-Invalid
}
Elseif($choice -eq 1)
{
    Set-All
}
Elseif($choice -eq 2)
{
    Set-Gpu1
}
Elseif($choice -eq 3)
{
    Set-Gpu0
}
```

However, rechoosing after an invalid choice won't work.

Comment: Thank you so much :D This is the only one that actually worked for this purpose. Now I need to actually debug how to start the miner lol.

Answer (score 0):

As for being new, that's fine, but it's best you take some video training via MS Virtual Academy or YouTube to see all things in action, before targeting just text / book reference. Seeing, it makes reading it much more concise. Well, for us visual learner types.

However, you've way over complicated this. Just us a simple if or case select statement. For example:

```
function Get-Choice()
{
    $choice = $null

    'Here are your choices (Select a number):'
    '1. All GPUs'
    '2. GPU 0'
    '3. GPU 1'

    $choice = Read-Host -Prompt 'Type the number and press enter to select what GPU(s) to mine with'
}

switch ($choice) 
    { 
        2 {
                    'GPU 1 Chosen'
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
                    miner.exe --server us-east.zec.slushpool.com --port 4444 --user ColinAndress.Colin --pass x --cuda_devices 1 --intensity 64 --eexit 3
                 } 
        3 {
                    'GPU 0 Chosen'
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
                    miner.exe --server us-east.zec.slushpool.com --port 4444 --user ColinAndress.Colin --pass x --cuda_devices 0 --intensity 64 --eexit 3
                 } 
        1  {
                    'All GPUs Chosen'
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
                    miner.exe --server us-east.zec.slushpool.com --port 4444 --user ColinAndress.Colin --pass x --cuda_devices 0 1 --intensity 64 64 --eexit 3
                 } 
        default  {
                    Write-Warning -Message 'Option is invalid. Pick again'
                    Get-Choice
                 }
    }
```

Also, there are a few things in your script that I don't get. Like choice of starting one code block from a given choice just to call a different one.